# how to reference class type in a LoadControl call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loadcontrol

In this example for loading a user control dynamically, how do I declare "TimeDisplay"? Can this be done in the code behind, or is it done in the ascx page? This is an example from a book, I guess there are assumptions made as to where the code files are located relative to one another?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ TimeDisplay ctrl = (TimeDisplay)Page.LoadControl("TimeDisplay.ascx"); 
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need to add a reference to the control in your aspx page:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/Controls_Path/TimeDisplay.ascx" %>
```

Comment: It may not cause errors, but how do you plan to reference the control in markup?

Answer (score 0):

To declare the control in markup, you'll need to register the control in the page directive or in the `web.config`. Registering the controls in `web.config` is usually preferrable because you can use the control anywhere in the application.

Config method:

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="uc1" src="~/controls/myusercontrol.ascx" tagName="myusercontrol" />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

Page directive method:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyUserControl" Src="~/controls/myusercontrol.ascx" %>
```

Comment: He wants to create the control "dynamically" why would you need to declare a tag in the markup.